# Moq verify invocation count from different methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to verify invocation count of a mocked method using moq in C# unit tests.

SUT seems like that:

```
public void Run(){ Foo();}

private void Foo(){

  ClassToBeMocked.MethodToBeMocked();
  Bar();

}

private void Bar(){

  ClassToBeMocked.MethodToBeMocked();

}
```

Test seems like that:

```
_mockClass.Setup(x=>x.MethodToBeMocked()).Returns(value);

Run();

_mockClass.Verify(x=>x.MethodToBeMocked(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

But what I want is to verify count of invocations in different methods like once from Foo() method, once from Bar() method.

**Is there a way to accomplish that using moq or do I need to use reflection?**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way, though it looks a bit messy. You can employ Callback method of moq along with StackTrace:

```
_mockClass.Setup(x=>x.MethodToBeMocked().Returns(value)
.Callback(() => {
    var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    var callerName = trace.GetFrame(5).GetMethod().Name;
    if (callerName == "Foo") CallFromFooMethod++;
    if (callerName == "Bar") CallFromBarMethod++;
});
```

Comment: Yes, actually it takes an argument but i didn’t specify because they take the same parameter both in Foo and Bar.

Comment: @HalilKiracı please try updated version, I hope it’ll help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. You could possibly mock an implementation which examines the call stack to track calling locations in a dictionary.

In general, I think you need to have a very specific reason to verify invocation counts in unit tests. The aim of the unit test is to verify that, given certain parameters, the method returns the expected result. It shouldn't concern itself with what happens under the hood to achieve that result. Requiring specific execution counts in order for the test to pass ties your unit test to the method implementation. A developer should be able to modify a method's implementation so it delivers an identical result without the test failing.

Comment: The reason is that return types of the methods are mostly void so not possible to assert results. The only way to test that kind of methods is to verify invocation count of mockable methods inside them, especially they have loops. I don’t know is there a more proper way to test void methods. You’re right, I also don’t want implementation to be tied with unit test so strictly. But sometimes in order to cover possible flows, you may need that kind of verifications.

Comment: Even if the methods return nothing, they most likely change the state or value of something. Assuming they do, your test methods could check those. If the things changed are marked `protected` or `private`, in some cases we mark them `internal` too and then use `InternalsVisibleTo` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` class to expose it to our unit test project.  (On the other hand if the calls are fire and forget - DB inserts or logging maybe - that's more integration testing than unit testing)